# Set a border around selecteditem in listbox WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, listbox, border

How do i set a style on the listbox to get a border around the selected item ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a Trigger for `IsSelected` in the ItemContainerStyle for the `ListBox`

```
<ListBox ...>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <!--...-->
</ListBox>
```

Comment: That's why I love WPF:)

Answer (score 2):

[FocusVisualStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613567.aspx) may be what are you looking for.