# How to set a border around listviewitem in WPF

Tags: wpf

My ListView should have following style:

- no border around the whole ListView (achieved)
- no highlighting when interacting with ListViewItem (achieved)
- border around **selected** ListViewItem (missing)

My ListView:

```
<ListView DisplayMemberPath="Name" BorderThickness="0" >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <!-- get rid of the highlighting -->
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <!-- style selected item -->
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983903/set-a-border-around-selecteditem-in-listbox-wpf) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297149/disable-blue-border-for-selected-listview-item), both doesn't work for me. I guess my problem is the template but I have no idea how to put a border around the selected ListViewItem.

**Update**

Working solution:

```
    <ListView DisplayMemberPath="Name" BorderThickness="0" >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <!-- get rid of the highlighting -->
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Border x:Name="Border">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this works. Add a Border around ContentPresenter an use controlTemplate Triggers

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                <Border x:Name="Border">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
```